# How to modify the system default background image

Tags: 10.04, desktop-background

I am about to ship a new 10.04 installed system to a customer. This is the 1st system that we are shipping with our preinstalled software and an additional hardware test platform, so I thought it would be a nice idea to have the desktop wallpaper include our company's logo.

What I want to do is just to add the logo to the default background image. the questions are:

1. Where are the set of backgrounds stored?
2. What are the rules for creating a custom background from scratch?
3. If I create a background from scratch, how do I add it to the *system's* background set (i.e., not just save it in the user's Pictures directory - I want it to be available to all future users of the machine)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- **Place** the image that you want to use as background image at `/usr/share/backgrounds/`
  Example:

  `sudo cp ~/Pictures/1.jpg /usr/share/backgrounds/1.jpg`
- **Edit** the `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/ubuntu-wallpapers.xml`. Remove the default images *(if you want to)* and add custom entries and finally **save** the file. (Make sure that the entries are done before the last line, that is, before the `</wallpapers>` line). Example:

`nits@nits-workstation:$ gksudo gedit/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/ubuntu-    wallpapers.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE wallpapers SYSTEM "gnome-wp-list.dtd">
<wallpapers>
   <wallpaper>
    <name>Custom_Back1</name>
    <filename>/usr/share/backgrounds/1.jpg</filename>
    <options>zoom</options>
    <pcolor>#000000</pcolor>
    <scolor>#000000</scolor>
    <shade_type>solid</shade_type>
   </wallpaper>
</wallpapers>
```

- Now whenever a user tries to change the background, the files listed according to the XML file only will show up by default in the **Appearances Preferences** window

Comment: Most welcome :)

Comment: so... how do I change the image in the login screen?

Comment: nvm, answered in another question.

Comment: and how is it making the image as default?

Answer (score 5):

The background images are stored in

`/usr/share/backgrounds`

For the files to appear in the list of available backgrounds for all users, including new ones, you'll need to add their information to an XML file in this folder :

`/usr/share/gnome-background-properties`

If you're customizing Ubuntu, take your cue from the `ubuntu-wallpapers.xml` file for the format to use for your background information.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Wish I could select two answers. @nitstorm got it just because of the extra effort :-)