# How to modify the system default login background image?

Tags: 10.04, gdm, login-screen, desktop-background

Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/66208/26972), I added a couple of modified background images to the backgrounds collection. Now, I want to select a different background for the login screen. How do I do that?

UPDATE: Just tried [David's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/66409/26972) on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 11.10. It seems like the file: `/usr/share/applications/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop` does no longer exist. Any idea on what I can use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the terminal and run the following commands

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow
```

Then logout, and you’ll see an Appearance window pop up. Change it to how you prefer it, then close it and login as usual.

When you have logged in after finishing the customizing, run this command to prevent the Appearance window from opening at the GDM screen every time.

```
sudo unlink /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop
```

or

If you want to install plymouth themes run the following command from your terminal

```
sudo aptitude install plymouth-theme-*
```

Now you can run the following commands to change login and plymouth screens

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth

gksu -u gdm dbus-launch gnome-appearance-properties
```

Comment: It looks like in 11.10 the /usr/share/applications/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop file does no longer exist. Any idea on what I should use instead?